# asp mvc update table row in database if exists, otherwise insert

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, exists, tablerow, insert-update

How can you check in ASP.NET MVC Razor if a table row exists in de database? if the table row  exists update it otherwise just add the object like the code below:

```
db.result.Add(object);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `Linq` to request

```
     `var data = (from record in db.result where record.field == yourInput select  record).FirstOrDefault();
     if (data == null)
     db.result.Add(object);
```

Comment: let's say `if (data!=null) {db.result.field = yourInput; db.SaveChanges();`}